# Windows Universal (IoT) Websocket server to broadcasting

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

I need something like library Websocket Sharp to Windows Universal. Im trying to build server on Windows 10 IoT to broadcast some data (temperature, and other events) and i want to build something like a streamer to broadcast live data from Arduino. 
In [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples) i can find only instructions to make a websocket client. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Universal Windows Platform (UWP) provides support for both client and server use of WebSockets. You may find a library named [IoTWeb](https://github.com/sensaura-public/iotweb) which allows you to embed a simple HTTP and WebSocket server into your UWP app. This library provides a simple HTTP server with WebSocket support.

```
class WebSocketHandler : IWebSocketRequestHandler
{
    private Dictionary<string,WebSocket> _webSockets = new Dictionary<string, WebSocket>();
    public event MessageRecivedHandler MessageRecived;
    private IdHelper _portMappings;

    public WebSocketHandler(IdHelper portMappings)
    {
        _portMappings = portMappings;
    }



    public void Connected(WebSocket socket)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        _webSockets.Add(guid, socket);


        socket.DataReceived += (webSocket, frame) => MessageRecived?.Invoke(_webSockets.First(x => x.Value == webSocket).Key,webSocket, frame);
        socket.ConnectionClosed += (webSocket) =>
        {
            var connection = _webSockets.First(s => s.Value == webSocket);
            _webSockets.Remove(connection.Key);
        };

        if (_portMappings.IsBindingPosible())
        {
            _portMappings.Bind(guid);

            var message = new ServerMessage()
            {
                ClientID = guid,
                Command = "Init",
                Value = _portMappings.CheckBinding(guid).ToString()
            };
            SendMessage(guid, message);
        }
        else
        {
            var message = new ServerMessage()
            {
                ClientID = guid,
                Command = "Init",
                Value = "Max Number Of Clients Reached. Please close connection"
            };
            SendMessage(guid, message);
        }


    }

    public bool WillAcceptRequest(string uri, string protocol)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public async Task BroadcastMessage(string message)
    {
        await ThreadPool.RunAsync((workItem) => _webSockets?.AsParallel().ForAll(webSocket => webSocket.Value.Send(message)));
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string guid, ServerMessage message)
    {
        await ThreadPool.RunAsync((workItem) => _webSockets?.First(x => x.Key == guid).Value.Send(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message)));
    }
    public delegate void MessageRecivedHandler(string guid, WebSocket socket, string message);
}
```

Comment: Is there possibility to show me which namespaces you exactly using in this class? I have some conflicts.

Comment: @Kamil, the `WebSocketHandler` is not in the library, it is a custom handler which inherits from `IWebSocketRequestHandler` for your requirement.

Comment: To everybody who searching informations in topic of "Windows IoT on Raspberry Pi": Dont waste your time. I don't know what is reason, but Windows 10 IoT on RBPi will make you angry, and maybe crazy. There are a lot of unexpected bugs, and errors, and autorestarts. Just use Raspbian and if you have to - docker. Thats all what you need. 
I wasted about 5 days to make it working.